# Android "hello world" app in C++ without JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to write a simple "Hello World" GUI (not CLI) app in C++ and run it on my Android device. I tried the Hello-JNI sample from Android NDK package, but it also uses some Java code and I want to do it in pure C++ way, without JNI. Is it even possible or do I *have to* use some Java wrapper?

It would be nice to do it the old way – without Eclipse, just a C++ code file + makefile.

Comment: Personally I use c4droid app to compile and export c++ as apk. It will manage the jni for you. For GUI and Sensors, I use sdl2 or sfml depending on project. For non GUI projects, c4droid will provide an open source terminal automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All traditional Android apps, particularly those with a user interface, will need an `Activity` that can be launched by the user from the home screen's launcher, and that `Activity` has to be in Java.

NDK developers are welcome to [use `NativeActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) as that `Activity`, so those developers do not have to mess with Java themselves. There is [a sample app](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na.html) demonstrating it use as part of the documentation.

> It would be nice to do it the old way – without Eclipse, just a C++ code file + makefile.

You certainly don't have to use Eclipse, and Eclipse support is ending in ~3 months anyway, but you do have to use the Android SDK and NDK toolchains to create an APK file, if you are trying to create a traditional Android app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just take C++ code and run it directly in Java. You need to interface it somehow. You can either do that with a JNI bridge file, where you create java methods that execute C++ code, or you can create an interface file that you then implement as "native" in a java class which calls C++ .so library file methods.

Comment: This is not true. It is possible to build an APK with 0% Java. See here: https://github.com/cnlohr/rawdrawandroid  and the corresponding video demonstration:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz_LvaN36Ag